# Hibernate Persistence Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
@Entity
Class A{

//assume proper annotations present
private Long id;
@OneToMany(@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   
private List<B> b;

//all getters and setters are present...

}
```

Code:

```
A a =//get a from data base using hibernate by id
//a contains b also
a.setId(null);
entityDao.persist(a);//line at which i am getting exception
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: B
```

When using merge instead of persist everything works fine. But i would like to know what was the problem with persist?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the primary key you're making the object detached hence before you can persist the detached object you would first have to reattach the object which merge does.